# Timed delayed auto page redirect JQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, multipage, timed-events

Hi I am trying to make a page redirect automatically to another page, in a JQM multi-page index. I also want the redirect to be delayed for about 3 seconds. So basically i want #behavior-summary (show up for 3 seconds) and go back to #order-summary automatically without clicking. I know there's probably a simple solution to this. I've tried many of the answers here, but the don't seem to work. I am using 
JQ 2.1.4 and JQM 1.4.5.

For a side not this is not a splash screen, it going to be a .gif that shows animation confirmation after a user input an item. right now i'm just using a button as you can see on #behavior-summary. The goal is to be able to remove the , no button just straight redirect after a specified period of time.

Here are some solutions that i've tried that does not work for some reason:

[Example 1](http://jsfiddle.net/yzvWy/14/)

[Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/v7ZRr/)

If anyone can help with this, i would greatly appreciate it

```
<div data-role="page" id="order-summary">
   <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Record Drink</h1>
        <a href="#nav-panel" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext">Menu</a>
   </div>
   <div data-role="content" id="summary-img">
        <img src="img/behavior_4.png"/>
        <a href="#behavior-summary" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-a" >Save</a>
   </div>
</div>    


<div data-role="page" id="behavior-summary">
    <div data-role="header" id="record-header">
        <h1>Record Drink</h1>
        <a href="#nav-panel" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext">Menu</a>
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content" id="summary-img">
        <img src="img/drink_1.gif"/>
        <a href="#order-summary" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-a" >Save</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the pageshow event of behavior-summary, and then a setTimeout with 3 second delay and a pagecontainer change method to go back to the first page:

```
$(document).on("pageshow","#behavior-summary", function(){ 
  setTimeout(function(){
    $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer( "change", "#order-summary", {} );
  }, 3000);
});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/7oLo33gs/)**

If you prefer the pagecontainer events:

```
$(document).on( "pagecontainershow", function( event, ui ) {
  if (ui.toPage.prop("id") == "behavior-summary" ){
    setTimeout(function(){
      $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer( "change", "#order-summary", {  } );
    }, 3000);  
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks i'm going to try this

Answer (score 0):

```
actual have not understand your whole Q, but if you are looking for a redirect then you can use a window.location.href = '#pagname or string'; or if you want to stop the setInterval then you can use clearInterval function

Please let me know if i can help you or i help understand the your pro
```

Comment: I just want page #behavior-summary to show up for 5 seconds and back to page #order-summary automatically without any clicking